# Implementing Comparable for a Node in Java

Tags: java, comparable

I'm new to Java, thus the questions might look trivial to some.
I've an implementation of a Node class, that uses a generic data type T. I want to implement a comparable to compare two instances of T.

This is my code.

```
private class Node<T> implements Comparable<T> {
        private T data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(T other) {
            if(this.data == other) return 0;
            if(this.data < other) return 1;
            if(this.data > other) return -1;
        }
    }
```

This code doesn't compile as Java throws bad operand type error. What is the correct way to write the compareTo function. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need the `T`s to be comparable between themselves.  What you want is basically just

```
private class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {
    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node<T> other) {
       return data.compareTo(other.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I just want to compare the two T values and not the two nodes then how do I implement the comparable.

Comment: What do you mean, compare the two `T` values?  If you have two `T` values, just call `t1.compareTo(t2)`.

Comment: I'm trying to do this. `private class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>  {
        private T data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public int compareTo(T other){
            return data.compareTo(other);
        }

    }`

Comment: I'm using this node in the implementation of a stack. So later when I call `if(((Comparable) item).compareTo(minValue)){
//do something
        }` I get a compilation error

Comment: Actually figured it out. Thanks.